# How to pass children in Jetpack Compose to a custom composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am curious if it is possible to pass in composables to a custom composables block. Which is then rendered in its definition. I was thinking a vararg + function literal approach could be taken and couldn't find any information.

```
//definition
@Composable
fun Content() {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        //insert a(), b(), ..., z() so that they render in the row
    }
}

//usage
Content() {
    a()
    b()
    ...
    z()
}
```

Does something like this exist already? You are able to use Jetpack Compose this way. The row implementation must handle the Text somehow.

```
Row(){
    Text("a")
    Text("b")
    Text("c")
}
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

After looking at the implementation of Row, RowScope and finding this piece of [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layout#create-custom). This can be achieved by the following code sample. The **[content](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layout#material-built-in)** function parameter with the type of `@Composable() () -> Unit` gets passed down into the row.

```
//definition
@Composable
fun MyCustomContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable() () -> Unit
) {
    Row(modifier = modifier) {
        content()
    }
}

//usage
MyCustomContent() {
    a()
    b()
    z()
}
```

Comment: "name it as you please" -- you may start getting Lint warnings. The official convention is that this parameter is named `content`.